# Magento frontend redirect error while using reverse proxy

Tags: apache, magento, reverse-proxy

We've been struggling with a problem involving a Magento website and a reverse proxy.

Server A is used as a reverse proxy (apache) and redirects incoming **subdomain.domain.com/appname** to **local-ip/appname** hosted on server B (apache as well).

What is really weird is that everything works fine on backend. We can login, modify stuff, everything perfectly normal there.

But on frontend nothing works and there is an infinite redirection.

However setting up Magento with **local-ip/appname** as the base url, and accessing it through **subdomain.domain.com/appname** (not with local-ip/appname)
works fine if accessed from local network.

As soon as Magento uses adress **subdomain.domain.com/appname** as base url, frontend gives an infinite redirection error.

If anyone has any input on that we would really appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, reverse proxy needed the directive

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

As it is set to Off by default there was an infinite redirection as Magento was trying to access the external address which was transformed as local ip by reverse proxy ans so on.
With `ProxyPreserveHost On` reverse proxy transmits original url to the website behind him. As a consequence Magento can be set up with external address as base url.